# c# To check if a year is a leap year without DateTime

Tags: c#

Having some trouble with a program, currently in my 2nd week of programming course so sorry if this isn't the best place to ask.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the year");
        a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        {
            if ((a % 4)  == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("It's a leap year.");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("It's not a leap year.");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Having lots of trouble with the formula for this.

Comment: why is there a `{ }`-block around the `if` statement?

Comment: Have you done any research? The programming formula for checking if an integer is a leap year is readily available on Google

Answer (score 6):

The [rules for a leap year are](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/leapyear.html)

- The year can be evenly divided by 4;
- If the year can be evenly divided by 100, it is NOT a leap year, unless;
- The year is also evenly divisible by 400. Then it is a leap year.

Hopefully that will help you figure out translating it in to code. I am not going to post the actual code due to this being homework, but I will give you some hints. To combine two checks use the `&&` operator to represent `AND`, `||` to represent `OR` and `!` to represent `NOT`.

The final formula will look something like

```
if ( a%4 == 0 __ (!(_____ == 0) __ (______ == 0))
```

You will need to fill in the blanks for yourself.

Comment: you should edit  your comment under the question then

Comment: @Benj Refresh, the comment has been deleted for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this..

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please Enter The Year:");
            int year = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            if (year%400 == 0 || (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Leap Year");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not Leap Year");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That should do. If you understand this code, you have clearly earned the point for the homework ... It really works :-)

```
    private static Boolean IsLeapYear(Int32 year)
    {
        if (-1 != ~(year & (1 | 1 << 1))) return false;

        if (0 == ((year >> 2) % 0x0019))
        {
            if (0 == (year / 0x0010) % 0x0019) return true;
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

The DateTime class has an IsLeapYear method

You can use like below:

```
 if(DateTime.IsLeapYear(a))
  {
   Console.WriteLine("It's a leap year")
  }
  else
  {
  Console.WriteLine("It's not a leap year")
  }
```

Comment: This is most likely a homework assignment teaching the students on how to combine multiple logical tests. He even specifically says he can't use the IsLeapYear check in the title

Comment: The question clearly asks about *without DateTime*. How is an answer that starts with *The DateTime class* relevant?